# question google maps and street navigation

Tags: google-maps

just want to ask something about google maps app and street navigation and "saved" data:

I am travelling between Moscow and Vladivostok (eastern shores). Before leaving (still has 3G/4G connection), I decided to check out the route and started the navigation feature. if for whatever reason I lose my net connection in the middle of Russia (which is 100% definite I think), will street navigation still work? I was hoping Google would have downloaded all the stuff needed when I started the navigation.

Thanks! :)

Comment: it's not offline as such since when I started the journey, I have net access. It's only when I was on my way where I lose net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, google maps navigation will not work without Internet connection! You can however install a navigation app which will work without Internet. For example HERE Maps. Don't forget to download maps for the area where you want to travel.